# How do I allow Pasting of data into a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, copy-paste

I have a [neat little javascript data grid](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/downloads/ActiveWidgets_Grid_Free_Edition__28641_p/) and I want people to be able to paste data into it.  I know there are security issues attached to accessing the clipboard, but I am wondering if there is a way to do it.  It is by far the most intuitive approach for the end user.

Is there some cunning hack I could do with, say, a text input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PASTE in browsers is not data aware. It is text-only. I suggest pasting into a textarea then parsing the data and inserting it into your grid.